# No guarda checkitem seleccionado en Sharedpreference

Tags: android, alertdialog

Buenas tardes

Tengo un AlertDialog singlechoice el cual lo lleno desde un array de objetos los cuales obtengo obtengo desde un webservices.

Bueno mi problema es que yo guardo el id del objeto seleccionado en las shapredpreferences para despues usarlas en un filtro en un metodo que mando al webservices.

todo va bien hasta donde yo guardo id del objeto seleccionado, el problema es que cuando yo selecciono otra opcion no me guarda ese id de ese objeto, si no que me sigue guardando el mismo que anteriormente tenia seleccionado.

Necesito saber que estoy haciendo mal o que me hace falta.

dejo mi codigo

Alertidslog donde lleno mi singlechoice y donde guardo el id del objeto seleccioando

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList){
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);
            //int size = ZonaArrayList.size() + 1;
            final String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
            // zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);
            for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
                //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
                zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescripcion();
            }
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
            alertdialog.setTitle("Selecciona la Zona a Visitar");
            alertdialog.setSingleChoiceItems(zona, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                            editor.putInt("Clientez",ZonaArrayList.get(0).getId());
                            editor.commit();

                        }
                    })
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            //Mandar a llamar metodo Clientes con el filtro
                            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
                            AsynClien task = new AsynClien(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString(),settings.getInt("Clientez",1),settings.getString("ONControlToken", "").toString(),settings.getInt("ONControlEmpresa",1));
                            //Call execute
                            task.execute();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alerdoalog = alertdialog.create();
            alerdoalog.show();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas obteniendo el valor del primer elemento del List (indice 0) :

```
ZonaArrayList.get(0).getId()
```

usa el valor de `wich` :

```
ZonaArrayList.get(wich).getId()
```

Quedaría:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("Clientez",ZonaArrayList.get(wich).getId());
    editor.commit();
}
```

Comment: si ya quedo gracias

Comment: el detalle que ahora traigo es que quiero si yo mando un id el cual no tiene registro mi borre la lista de clientes que tengo

Comment: Eso sería en la BD? o en donde? si quieres agrega otra pregunta referente a ese detail, para que la vean los desarrolladores.

Comment: despues te paso mi apk